# How to convert inp to shp with Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, convert, pipe-network

How would I convert an EPANET .inp file into python lists in order to convert it to .shp files?

Comment: That file extension is associated with [at least a dozen applications](http://filext.com/file-extension/INP), of which several plausibly would be used with a GIS. Please edit this post to indicate what software created the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18097405/737471

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the documentation, it looks like you should be able to right-click and hit *Create Shapefiles*.  That is of course assuming you have the program integrated into the Windows shell.  See [the documentation](http://epanet.de/documentation/inptools_manual.html.en) for more information.

Comment: I am not trying to do this with INPTOOLS but develop a python script.

Comment: Do you have *epanettools* installed for python?

Comment: No, I do not have epanettools installed and I am unable to install it.

Comment: @user27630 Please use the **edit** button on your question to revise it with these additional requirements that are emerging as (temporary) comments.

Comment: user27630 look at @Luke's comment.  It links to another question that links directly to their site for download.  After downloading, if you have problems, it would probably be best to contact their support since the documentation is pretty sparse.  *This assumes you're running a Windows installation too.*  Looks like this supports up to Vista, although you may be able to use it in other versions.